# Remote debugging on HPUX

Tags: remote-debugging, hp-ux

I am trying to do remote debugging on HPUX using WDB but am not really getting anywhere.
Any ideas or links to decent tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

[HP WDB documentation](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=09080f1bace021100f1bace02110275d6e10RCRD)